# Closure : Use unresolved identifier 'self'

Tags: swift

I'm parsing the Swift Language Guide tutorial (from Apple iOS dev library) and for every chapter I create a separate swift file.
In each file I create multiple functions where I isolate snippets of code that they provide. Everything worked on until testing the Strong Reference Cycles for Closures. 
 For some reason if the class that contains a closure (for a computed property) is declared inside a function, then the closure cannot see the "self" reference of the enclosing class.  Any ideas why ? 
 It works fine if the class is not declared inside a function.

```
func strongRefClosure() {
    class HTMLElement {

        let name: String
        let text: String?

        lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
            if let text = self.text {
                return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
            } else {
                return "<\(self.name) />"
            }
        }

        init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
            self.name = name
            self.text = text
        }

        deinit {
            println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
        }
    }

    var paragraph: HTMLElement? = HTMLElement(name: "p", text: "hello, world")
    println(paragraph!.asHTML())
}
```

Comment: I think it's a bug.  You should [report it to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Just wondering if anyone opened this radar and might have a link? I can open one if nobody else has already

Comment: Apple replied : Duplicate of 16888679 (Open), but I cannot find or see the content of that bug report, their bug database seems to be private, you can only see your reports. Couldn't find it on [Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/page/1) either.

Answer (score 4):

Looks very much like a bug (or at least, a behaviour of function-local structs/classes I can’t find documented).  This works fine:

```
struct Foo {
    let someVal = 5
    lazy var someLazy: String = {
        return toString(self.someVal)
    }()
}

var foo = Foo()
foo.someLazy // string "5"
```

But this doesn’t:

```
func outer() {
    struct Foo {
        let someVal = 5
        lazy var someLazy: String = {
            // error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'
            return toString(self.someVal)
        }()
    }

    var foo = Foo()
    foo.someLazy
}
```

An inner struct inside an outer struct works, though:

```
struct Outer {
    struct Foo {
        let someVal = 5
        lazy var someLazy: String = {
            return toString(self.someVal)
        }()
    }

    var foo = Foo()
}

var outer = Outer()
outer.foo.someLazy
```

As @JeremyP says, you should [file a radar](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Posted a ticket to Apple. I'll update the thread after receiving their feedback.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have this bug in XCode 8GM, Swift 3, iOS 10.0.

#### tl;dr

- Closure-as-instance-property has bug
- Closure-as-computed-property is cured!

#### Actual code

Buggy:

```
let permissionStatusHandler = { (status: CKApplicationPermissionStatus, error: Error?) in
        switch status {
        case .granted:
            self.fetchUserRecordID() // Buggy: Use of unresolved identifier 'self'
        case .initialState:
            self.requestDiscoverability() // Buggy: Use of unresolved identifier 'self'
        case .couldNotComplete:
            error.then { print(#function, $0.localizedDescription) }
            fallthrough
        case .denied:
            self.iCloud.presentiCloudAlert(for: status)
        }
    }
```

Kosher:

```
var permissionStatusHandler: (CKApplicationPermissionStatus, Error?) -> () { return
        { (status: CKApplicationPermissionStatus, error: Error?) in
            switch status {
            case .granted:
                self.fetchUserRecordID()
            case .initialState:
                self.requestDiscoverability()
            case .couldNotComplete:
                error.then { print(#function, $0.localizedDescription) }
                fallthrough
            case .denied:
                self.iCloud.presentiCloudAlert(for: status)
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps some other soul out there.