# Swift - Use of unresolved identifier 'self' - from Closure in a Class

Tags: swift

I am trying to reference a property in my class from a closure declared in my class. I cannot access self from inside my closure, and I'm assuming self would refer to the Class API from within my closure.

I want to declare a closure that I use later as a parameter to pass to a URLSession dataTask (It works without the one error line). I get the error listed in the title.

> Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

I've been writing swift for an entire day now and am just trying things out as a sandbox, so I fully expect some criticism.

```
class Api {

    struct Location {
        var name = String()
        var author = String()
        var averageRating: String?
        var id = Int()
        var lat = Double()
        var lon = Double()
        var type = String()
    }

    var locations = [Location]()

    var doSomething = {(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] {
                    let myResult = json["results"] as! [[String: Any]]
                    var location : Location! = Location()
                    for jsonLocation in myResult {
                        if let name = jsonLocation["name"]{location.name = name as! String}
                        if let author = jsonLocation["author"]{location.author = author as! String}
                        if let id = jsonLocation["id"]{location.id = id as! Int}
                        if let lat = jsonLocation["lat"]{location.lat = lat as! Double}
                        if let lon = jsonLocation["lon"]{location.lon = lon as! Double}
                        if let type = jsonLocation["type"]{location.type = type as! String}

                        //ERROR IS HERE, Why does self not reference class API?
                        self.locations.append(location)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("error in JSONSerialization")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366270/closure-use-unresolved-identifier-self), but this example is different so I wasn't sure if it was the same bug or me not understanding swift.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a computed property instead of a function for doSomething?

Comment: Nope, simply that I didn't think I needed a function. But I can simply use it. I was mostly just trying to learn to use a closure. I understand a function is a type of closure, but past that, I don't fully know why both exist.

Comment: Yah so the fix is making it a function, but I still don't understand why a closure, which a function is a type of, doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rahul's explanation is correct, but the suggested answer is ever so slightly incomplete.

Here is a complete solution:

1. Declare the `doSomething` property as `lazy` as Rahul suggested. A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. In other words this closure will not be evaluated until the doSomething property is called at run-time, at which point `self` is guaranteed to exist. See [Lazy Stored Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID257) in the Swift Programming Language for more details.
2. Add a type annotation to the `doSomething` property so the compiler doesn't have to infer the type at compile time, which apparently it can't do because the closure includes `self`. See [Type Safety and Type Inference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID322) in the Swift Programming Language for more details.

So the complete declaration is:

```
...
lazy var doSomething: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void = { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
...
```

ps. Welcome to Swift programming! It's a fantastic language and really fun. I hope you enjoy it as much as I do.

Comment: The second issue here regarding the required type annotation appears to no longer be required as of Swift 3.1. I just tested this on macOS and IBM's Swift Sandbox which allows you to run different versions of Swift in a Linux environment: https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/

Answer (score 6):

You are not able to access `self` because it is not available when you are calling inside the closure as initialization hasn't happened yet and so compiler gives you the error.

The fix would be to user `lazy` var as this will defer the `self` call because lazy var get called only after initialisation.

```
 lazy var doSomething = { your closure goes here }
```

Comment: I still get the same issue with adding the word lazy.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same questions as you and I solve it using `lazy var`
Here is a quick example

My originally code is:

```
class MyClass {
    let callback:()->() = {
        self.foo()   // Compile error: Use of unresolved identifier "self"
    }

    func foo() {
        print("bar")
    }
}
```

It compile error at that line I use `self`
But I change it to

```
class MyClass {
    lazy var callback:()->() = {
        [unowned self] in
        self.foo()
    }

    func foo() {
        print("bar")
    }
}

let c = MyClass()
c.callback()
```

that solved the problem

References:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html
http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/
[Shall we always use [unowned self] inside closure in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift)

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. :) Note that with value types you will still run into the *Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter* [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41941810) when using `lazy`, so be sure to simply add `[self]` to the closure capture list.
EDIT: forgot to link to the aforementioned issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `var locations = [Location]()` with this `var locations : [Location]?`

and  `var location : Location! = Location()` with `self.locations =  [Location]()` and  `self.locations.append(location)` with `self.locations?.append(location)`

You will be good to go!

lazy var is too complex a concept to grasp I guess but you can use it this way:

```
lazy var locations:[Location] = {
        let locations = Location()
        return locations
    }()
```

Comment: I still get the same issue with both fixes. If I remove self from the locations after making it lazy it says "Instance member 'locations' cannot be used on type 'Api'"